# Login Beanstalk API

Tags: c#, http-request

Estou Tentando fazer uma integração com o serviço do **`http://api.beanstalkapp.com/`** e estou com problemas para fazer a request em C#, sempre me retorna o erro abaixo:

> An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: A conexão subjacente estava fechada: Erro inesperado em um envio.

Segue o codigo:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlBeanstalk);
request.Method = "GET";
request.Accept = "application/json";
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password)));
WebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Qual o endereço que você está tentando fazer a requisição?

Comment: https://{domain}.beanstalkapp.com/api/users/current.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criei uma conta na Beanstalk só pra poder testar isso.

Tem duas coisas erradas no seu código:

1. A requisição **não** deve ser feita sobre HTTPS (eu sei que o exemplo no próprio manual mostra isso, aparentemente, ele está errado)

   Troque o endereço para **`http://{domain}.beanstalkapp.com/api/users/current.json`**
2. Isso não está bem claro, mas parece que você está enviando **`usuario:senha`** no header `Authorization`. O certo é enviar **`usuario:token`**. O token deve ser gerado em https://domain.beanstalkapp.com/access_tokens

Comment: Muito Obrigado! realmente funcionou com http, já a questão da senha ou Token funciona as duas.